# What will be the formatted csv to add the email's on email automation

Tags: content-management, role-management

What will be the formatted csv to add the email's on email automation, If possible provide the provide the example of related csv

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, what you're asking for is format of CSV file which can be used in Sitecore List Manager to use `Create list from file` option:

[image: Sitecore Create list from file]

or from Contact List details view

In both cases the minimal necessary CSV file is the same:

```
john.doe@email.local;John;Doe
jane.dean@email.local;Jane;Dean
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you are asking the formatting of .csv file which you can use in EXM.

You can try the below steps :

To create a list in EXM:

1. Open EXM and click Create.
2. From the Create List column, click the type of list that you want to create:

**Recipient list from file** – create a contact list and import the recipients from a CSV file.

**Recipient list from existing list** – create a contact list that is based on an existing contact list.

**Empty recipient list** – create an empty contact list that you can use to add recipients to automatically, for example, from a subscription form.

**Segmented list from all recipients** – create a segmented list with all contacts included as the list source.

**Segmented list from existing list** – create a segmented list that is based on an existing contact list.

[image]

You can create .csv file in Microsoft Excel by selecting the below option.

[image]

It will create `.csv` file in comma delimited.

You can refer this link :

- https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/exm/90/email-experience-manager/create-a-list-in-the-email-experience-manager.html